# WordPress Hide Page Editor Based on ID?

Tags: wordpress

Is there anyway to hide the post editor wysiwyg on a page based on the page ID?

I have a few custom meta boxes and dont need it on this specific page..

I've tried the following but it doesnt do anything, the page has the id of 75 but its still showing up?

```
function remove_pages_editor(){
  if(get_the_ID() == 75) {
     remove_post_type_support( 'post', 'editor' );
  } // end if
 } // end remove_pages_editor
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'remove_pages_editor' );
```

Any ideas..?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with an earlier hook, [`do_action('load-' . $page_hook);`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-admin/admin.php#L147).

```
add_action( 'load-post.php', 'hide_specific_editor_so_15154969' );

function hide_specific_editor_so_15154969()
{
    if( '75' == $_GET['post'] && 'edit' == $_GET['action'] )
        remove_post_type_support( 'post', 'editor' );
}
```

Comment: Oh, I was testing that as a [**Must Use** plugin](http://codex.wordpress.org/Must_Use_Plugins)... And just checked, it *doesn't work* neither as a normal plugin nor inside `functions.php`. Updated the Answer.

Comment: My bad, in my tests it works in `functions.php`, as a normal plugin and as a mu-plugin. I re-checked with the incorrect ID, hence my confusion.

Comment: The screen you need to target is `/wp-admin/post.php?post=75&action=edit`? ::: If you can do it, try disabling all plugins and swapping to TwentyEleven to see if there's a conflict...

Comment: Still not working, it works for page-template with this function http://pastie.org/7121893 can it be edited for page id?

Comment: It works if you change `remove_post_type_support(...)`> to `echo '<style type="text/css">#postdivrich{display:none!important;}</style>';`. It doesn't remove the editor but rather hides it. A quick fix.

Comment: @kevin, yep, but then it should be hooked into `admin_head` instead of `load`. user4630, in that pastie you're dealing with `page` post type, ain't this the source of the confusion?

Comment: @rbasolfilo, yep, but as i said, a quick fix. I'll try to check that hook. Thanks.